# I am getting an error "javax.servlet package not found" when i m trying to compile the following java code

Tags: java, servlets, classpath

I am getting an error javax.servlet.* package not found while trying to compile the following source code :

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;

public class servlet1 extends HttpServer
{
public void doPOST(HttpServletRequest req , HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException,IOException

{
String uid = req.getParameter("T1");
String pwd = req.getParameter("T2");

PrintWriter pw=res.getWriter();
pw.println(uid);
pw.println(pwd);


}
}
```

I'm using java 6.0 and tomcat 6.0 softwares

Please tell me what should I do for successfully compiling this file?

Comment: Sounds obvious, but... have you looked at the clas path? If you are using eclipse IDE you should have the server runtime libreary.

Comment: The exact answer depends on the toolset used. Are you fiddling low level with notepad.exe and javac.exe? Or are you using an IDE like Eclipse, Netbeans, IntelliJ, etc?

Answer (score 3):

When you add servlet.jar or j2ee.jar to your classpath you will have to fix the doPost signature. It should be doPost, not doPOST

Comment: Nice spotted! I really don't know when was the last time I wrote a doPost with all this auto-generating code hehe.

Comment: `extends HttpServer` is also completely wrong. Perhaps OP was not reading the right books/tutorials/guides.

Answer (score 0):

You need the Java EE Jars in your Classpath. You can find them in the lib-directory of your app-server (tomcat, glassfish etc.)

http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/overview-summary.html